# Is this infinite product always irrational?

Tags: infinite-product

Let n be a positive integer$>1$. Is the infinite product $n^{1/n}(n^2)^{1/n^2}(n^4)^{1/n^4}(n^8)^{1/n^8}...$   always irrational?

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly yes, but it would be extremely surprising if any of these could be proven to be irrational.  It's hard enough proving something irrational when you have a closed form formula for it.

Comment: This is a question of Indian Regional Mathematical Olympiad- 1993.

Comment: @did Sorry, my mistake, Thank you very for your comment. I delete my answer.